# Generate a main package containing external packages

Tags: c#, biml

I am using VS 2012 with SQL Server 2012 and BIML. 
I would like to generate a "main" package containing several packages in it, quite simple.
Here is the code I am using, it contains c# code which simply do a query on a DB to retrieve the name of tables (which are generated by a package with the same name).
I tested the code without c# code (with one external package) and it is working...
Can somebody could help me please ?

Thanks in advance !!

```html
    <Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Packages>
    <Package Name="Test" ConstraintMode="Linear">
    <#  string MyConnectionString ="Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=DB1;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False; Integrated Security=SSPI" ; 
  string SourceTableName; 
  DataTable MyDataTable; 
  MyDataTable = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(MyConnectionString,"SELECT t.TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND t.TABLE_TYPE ='Base Table' AND t.TABLE_NAME='Table1'"); 
    
        foreach(DataRow row in MyDataTable.Rows)
        { 
            SourceTableName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().ToUpper() ;  
    #>
     <Tasks>
        <ExecutePackage  Name="Test">
           <ExternalProjectPackage Package="<#SourceTableName#>.dtsx"/>
        </ExecutePackage> 
     </Tasks>
<# } #>                      
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Biml>
<!--Directives:-->
<#@ template language ="C#" tier ="2" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="Varigence.Biml.CoreLowerer.SchemaManagement" #>
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Error 0 ; missing

Comment: Hey, where does the **ExternalDataAccess** class come from? from which namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing an equals in your snippet:

Change `<#SourceTableName#>.dtsx` to `<#=SourceTableName#>.dtsx`

Comment: iamdave => you got the point !! you desserve it 
Thanks a lot